# Diffeomorphism groups of orbifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, orbifolds

A lot is known about geometric and topological properties of diffeomorphism groups of surfaces (here, I am mainly thinking about the work of Smale and Eells-Elworthy). Is there anything known for orbisurfaces ? My first guess would be that many of these groups must have contractible components since singular points impose extra conditions somewhat similar to fixed points. Is there a good reference on this topic ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result you want can be found in the following paper:

MR0955816 (89h:30028)
Earle, Clifford J.(1-CRNL); McMullen, Curt(1-MSRI)
Quasiconformal isotopies. Holomorphic functions and moduli, Vol. I (Berkeley, CA, 1986), 143--154,
Math. Sci. Res. Inst. Publ., 10, Springer, New York, 1988.

What they prove is actually pretty remarkable.  Namely, let $S$ be a hyperbolic surface.  Then there is a family $\phi_t$ of self-maps of $\text{Diff}^{0}(S)$ such that $\phi_0$ is the identity, such that $\phi_1$ is the constant map taking each diffeomorphism to the identity diffeomorphism, and such if $f \in \text{Diff}^0(S)$ commutes with a finite order diffeomorphism $g$ of $S$, then $\phi_t(f)$ also commutes with $g$ for all $t$.  In other words, you can contract $\text{Diff}^0(S)$ in way that doesn't break any symmetries.

Now assume that $\Sigma = S / \Gamma$ is a good hyperbolic orbifold, where $\Gamma$ is a finite group of diffeomorphisms of $S$.  The identity component of the orbifold diffeomorphism group of $\Sigma$ is then homeomorphic to 
$$\text{Diff}^{0}(S,\Gamma) := \langle f \in \text{Diff}^{0}(S)\ |\ gfg^{-1}=f\ \text{for all}\ g \in \Gamma \rangle \subset \text{Diff}^{0}(S)$$
The null-homotopy $\phi_t$ preserves $\text{Diff}^{0}(S,\Gamma)$, so it is contractible.

(EDIT : I made a slight fix to the definition of the orbifold diffeomorphism above.  It doesn't change the argument.  Thanks to Tom Church for pointing it out to me!).

Comment: Thanks for this quick and illuminating answer. Do you know if some of those results extend to non-hyperbolic orbifolds ?

Comment: They fail even in the classical case for non-hyperbolic surfaces (for instance, for the sphere or the torus).

Comment: Well, my question was badly formulated. Here's a second try: Do you know any results on the homotopy type of diffeomorphism groups of non-hyperbolic orbisurfaces (à la Smale), regardless of the techniques used ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of any such results.  I'd be interesting in hearing about any ones that you find!